# QTreeview is not defaulting to the path I set. It instead shows the default C: and D: drives

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtreeview

I'm making a GUI application and have included a treeview widget from which you can load files. I set the root path to the documents folder but even after doing that it shows me the default (C:) and (D:) drives when I run the application which I then have to wade through to get to the documents folder. How do I get it to work?

```
    self.treeView_directory = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.widget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.treeView_directory.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.treeView_directory.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.treeView_directory.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 638))
    self.treeView_directory.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 16777215))
    self.treeView_directory.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.treeView_directory.setObjectName("treeView_directory")
    self.model = QFileSystemModel()
    self.model.setRootPath('C:\\Users\\Rada1\\Documents')
    self.treeView_directory.setModel(self.model)
    self.treeView_directory.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.treeView_directory, 0, 0, 2, 1)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#example-usage) says that you must set the root index on the view to show a specific directory. Try with `self.treeView_directory.setRootIndex('C:\\Users\\Rada1\\Documents')`.

Comment: A version of what you recommended worked. `self.treeView_directory.setRootIndex(self.model.index('C:\\Users\\Rada1\\Documents'))` seemed to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @EArtemis, sorry, wrong copy&paste from mobile. Yes, `setRootIndex` obviously need a QModelIndex.